# CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY during tf export mode despite turning gpu completely off already

Tags: tensorflow

I am currently running a few Tensorflow training jobs with gpu and am trying to export models from one such job. I have set

```
os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'
```

both in code and in terminal. Also I have removed all mentions of gpu devices in the training code, as well as moved graph.pbtxt away. I used inspect_checkpoint.py to see that the model checkpoint keys contain no mention of gpu either. I have also set

```
session_config = tf.ConfigProto(
    device_count={'GPU': 0 if export else config.num_gpus},
    allow_soft_placement=True,
    gpu_options=None if export else tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True))
```

Still I am getting the following error message towards the end of export:

```
    2018-09-15 03:20:30.597742: E 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:158] Internal: failed 
initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 0: Internal: failed 
call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; total memory 
reported: 16936861696

nvidia-smi | head -20

Sat Sep 15 03:25:28 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.130                Driver Version: 384.130                   |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   35C    P0    50W / 250W |  15800MiB / 16152MiB |     89%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   35C    P0    37W / 250W |      0MiB / 16152MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:83:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   36C    P0    37W / 250W |      0MiB / 16152MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   3  Tesla V100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:84:00.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   38C    P0    39W / 250W |      0MiB / 16152MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: What tensorflow version do you have? Can you provide a minimal example? The environment variable approach works for me.

Comment: A bit hard to reproduce the problem since it only happened when I am at GPU memory limit in the first card.